# saving script variables from php variables in while loop

Tags: javascript, php, variables, while-loop

been trying to save my data from my while loop to script variables but no success. Did an example if how I want to save my php data to script variables. This doesn't work for me. Anyone have any idea? Don't want to save all data manually. Very greatful for answers! Ask if you don't understand :)

```
$id = 0;
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
$id = $id + 1;

$data = $rows['data'];

echo "<script>";

     echo "var data" . $id . " = " . $data . ";"; //???

echo "</script>";

}
```

Comment: You have error in developer's console or what?

Comment: don't do this. You're spitting out arbitrary text into a javascript context. That means you have to generate VALID javascript. If any of the `$data` values you output contain a `'`, you'll be producing JS syntax errors. **ALWAYS** use http://php.net/json_encode for this kind of thing. Plus, you need to learn about arrays. They'll make your life FAR easier than generating a few zillion `data1`, `data2`, `data3`, etc... variables.

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off producing an array on the client, rather than discrete `data0`, `data1`, `data2`, ..., `dataN` variables?

Comment: You are also overwrite the `$data` variable, so the next iteration of the while loop is going have issues.  I'd rename that variable within the while loop.

Comment: Well, this is an example I got from another guy, dont really know what is possible to do :P @MarcB

Comment: @T.J. - no, he's calling `mysql_fetch_array($data)` and then has `$data = $rows['data']` two lines further down, thus overwriting `$data`.

Comment: @NathanLoding: Sorry, I thought you were talking about the *client-side* var for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

The best thing to do here would almost certainly be to create an array (on the PHP side), and then output the entire array at once.

Assuming you've built an array in `$array`, here's how you would output it:

```
echo "<script>var data = " . json_encode($array) . ";</script>"
```

More on `json_encode` [in the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), but basically it encodes the PHP data as valid [JSON](http://json.org). Since JSON is a subset of JavaScript object and array initializer syntax, you can safely output JSON text as the right-hand side of an assignment, as above.

In the client-side script, you'd access each item via `data[0]`, `data[1]`, etc. up through `data[data.length - 1]`.

---

Separately, note what [Nathan Loding](https://stackoverflow.com/users/138148/nathan-loding) pointed out in a comment on the question:

> ...[you're] calling `mysql_fetch_array($data)` and then [have] `$data = $rows['data']` two lines further down, thus overwriting `$data`...

...which will tend to mess up your fetch loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are duplicating the script tag on every iteration.
you also need to surround the data in double or single quotes.
But it is not so safe..

```
$id = 0;
$data = "";
$vars = "";
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
  $id = $id + 1;
  $data = $rows['data'];
  $vars .= "var data" . $id . " = \"" . addslashes( $data ). "\";"; //???
}

echo "<script>";

echo  $vars;

echo "</script>";

}
```

Comment: I think you mean `$vars = "";` ;)